# Instagram's user media API returns missing video URLs

Tags: instagram-api

I use [Instagram's users media API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent_self) to retrieve the list of videos but it's empty.

When I send the request, I get all the posts in response as expected but the video resource values are `null`.

[image: Empty video in response]

```
jsonp(`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/${USER_ID}/media/recent/?access_token=${TOKEN}`, null, (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  } else {
    res.data && res.data.forEach(item => {
      this.news.push(item)
    })
    console.log(this.news)
  }
});
```